# Plain text emails in Gmail

Tags: email, text, gmail, sendmail, send

How do I get plain text emails to show up correctly in Gmail?

They are in my email like this:

```
 Hello ZX,
 Congratulations on creating your LessonShark Account!

 There are two important parts to your LessonShark account that can help you grow and  manage your student roster:
```

But show up like so:

```
Hi ZX,

Congratulations on creating your LessonShark Account!



There are two important parts to your LessonShark account that can help you grow and manage your student roster:
```

Well this happen for other email clients too?

Comment: Are you sending them as HTML in the 1st place? an you put a sample of code you use to write the email?

Comment: Maybe you should open the email in Gmail and click "show as original" so check if the email has been sent in plain text, or in HTML (as I suspect)